# Best ffmpeg flags to ensure the portability of a mix & transcode process

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am the maintainer of a software which use `ffmpeg` to automatically mix & 
transcode two input stream into a single output with a video & audio track. I
am currently facing some portability issues and would like to improve my use
of `ffmpeg` to be ensure that my application will be as portable as possible:

- Will work on almost all OS & distro
- Will work with old ffmpeg releases (debian squeeze still use ffmpeg 0.5.10)

My first source is an FLV or mp4 file. It contains two streams: audio & video. I 
don't care about the video, it not included in the final file.

The second source is a list of PNG or JPG images. They will be used to create 
the video stream using `image2`.

The output must be a file with two streams: audio & video. I have no strong 
requirement regarding the container, the audio codec and the video codec. They 
only need to be easily available on any OS/device. I want to preserve the audio 
quality as much as possible. The video stream is only a set of static slides. 
It would be great to minimize the size of the output file.

According to this description, which flags/container/codecs would you use?

---

The description of the current process follows:

1. Extract the audio track from the first source

   ```
   ffmpeg -v error -i source_1_path -vn -acodec libvorbis audio_track.ogg
   ```
2. Create the final file

   ```
   ffmpeg -v error -f image2 -r 1 -i frame_pattern.jpg -i audio_track.ogg output.avi
   ```

I was thinking that ffmpeg would automatically use the most suitable audio/video 
codecs & settings. Unfortunately it fails on some Linux distributions
(`[ac3 @ 0x1e60380] invalid bit rate` with `0.8.6-6:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.10.1` for
example).

It would obviously be better to do it in a single pass rather than creating a
temporary audio track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `ffmpeg` versions and packaging `ffmpeg` yourself

If someone's using `ffmpeg` 0.5.10, then you're really not to blame if something doesn't work. The number one cause of problems with `ffmpeg` commands (at least from my experience) is an outdated version. Between 0.5 and recent 1.2, there are literally thousands of fixed bugs and hundreds of new features. Most notably, they've changed (and removed) a few command line options, which break some workflows.

Note that Ubuntu, due [to some circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756), doesn't really use `ffmpeg` from the FFmpeg project, but actually uses Libav's `avconv`. In newer versions of Ubuntu, that is. Old versions of Ubuntu still supplied a binary called `ffmpeg` that came from Libav, which is broken and outdated, but people still think it comes from FFmpeg. Bottom line: You can't and shouldn't trust your user to have a working `ffmpeg` binary on their system.

There are [many projects that include part of the FFmpeg tools](http://ffmpeg.org/projects.html), and you could incorporate [a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) with your software if that's not a legal issue (IANAL, so please check). The only downside I see here is that older kernels might not run all static builds.

---

That all being said, here's what should work everywhere, under the assumption that `ffmpeg` was compiled with `libx264` and `libmp3lame` enabled. The original command you had wouldn't work reliably [because Vorbis audio is problematic in AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats), and the AC3 encoder that is auto-selected for AVI might chocke on some inputs. Plus, you'd re-encode your audio from Vorbis to AC3, which deteriorates the quality.

#### Extract audio to MP3

Rather export to MP3 audio, e.g. with 320 kBit/s CBR or VBR of 4 (LAME's `-V` equivalent). The latter might not work on old versions because of the `:a` suffix.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i source_1_path -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k audio_track.mp3
ffmpeg -v error -i source_1_path -vn -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 4 audio_track.mp3
```

#### Combine with H.264 video

For combining, we'll use x264 video (an H.264 encoder):

```
ffmpeg -v error -f image2 -r 1 -i frame_pattern.jpg -i audio_track.mp3 \
-acodec copy -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

Here you simply copy the audio stream instead of having `ffmpeg` re-encode it. This will help you retain the original quality.

As for video, note that not all devices can play H.264 out of the box. Some might only play H.264 with the baseline profile, which you set with `-profile:v baseline` in newer `ffmpeg`, or `-vprofile baseline` in some versions around 0.7 (not sure which… it was undocumented back then), or `-vpre baseline` for [really old versions that used internal presets](http://juliensimon.blogspot.co.at/2009/01/howto-ffmpeg-x264-presets.html) instead of relying on the x264 encoder library.

#### Alternative: Combine with MPEG-4 video

If H.264 is not an option you could try MPEG-4 Part II video—here with 2 MBit/s bitrate set through `-vb`:

```
ffmpeg -v error -f image2 -r 1 -i frame_pattern.jpg -i audio_track.mp3 \
-acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 -vb 2M output.mp4
```

The option should be `-b:v` now, but the old alias still works.

Comment: Thanks for your rational and valuable answer. I will use it as a foundation. Sadly it confirms my feeling that portability is not so easy to achieve. Regarding old versions in the wild, it is part of the game. You can't blame users for using stable distributions, but you can blame projects which don't care about (back|for)ward compatibility ;)